# Convert 1-D array of discrete values to n-D array of continuous values in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

What is best way of doing: given a 1-D array of discrete variables size N (here N=4) and X is the number of unique elements, I am trying to create a multidimensional array of size (N*X) where elements are 1 or 0 depending on the occurrence of elements in the 1-D array, e.g. Following array_1D (N=4 and X=3) will result in array_ND of size 3*4:

```
array_1D = np.array([x, y, z, x])
array_ND = [[1 0 0 1]
            [0 1 0 0]
            [0 0 1 0]]
```

Thanks,

Aso

Comment: Your result will not be NxN--even your example is 3x4.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser you are right. I corrected the question after your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(np.unique(a)[..., None] == a).astype(np.int)
```

You can leave out the `.astype(np.int)` part if you want a boolean array. Here we have used [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)  (the `[..., None]` part) to avoid explicit looping.

Broken down, as suggested in the comments:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1])
>>> unique_elements = np.unique(a)
>>> result = unique_elements[..., None] == a
>>> unique_elements
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> result
array([[ True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I was just about to give almost the same answer. :)  You should probably separate this into two steps.  The user will want to save the array returned by `np.unique(a)`, in order to know the meaning of the values in the array.

Comment: Thanks @MrE for your perfect answer. Numpy is just great!

Answer (score 2):

If the initial array contains valid indexes from `0` to `n - 1` then you can write

```
eye = np.eye(3)
array_1D = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0])
array_ND = eye[array_1D]
```

The resulting matrix will be

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

which is the transpose of the one you expect.

What's happening here is that numpy uses the elements of `array_1D` as row indices of `eye`. So the resulting matrix contains as many rows as the elements of `array_1D` and each one of them relates to the respective element. (`0` relates to `1 0 0`, etc.)